# Slider with progress of downloaded audio

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, slider, dependency-properties

I'm developing a slider with progress rectangle[see image].
This code doesn't works to set width dynamically

```
public class AudioSlider : Slider, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public AudioSlider() {
      DefaultStyleKey = typeof(AudioSlider);
    }
    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    #endregion
    private double _trwidth;
    public double TrackProgressWidth {
      get { return _trwidth; }
      set {
        _trwidth = value; OnPropertyChanged("TrackProgressWidth");
      }
    }

...
```

xaml.
default style...

```
<Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalFillLoaded" Height="12" MaxWidth="{Binding TrackProgressWidthMax,ElementName=audio}" Width="{Binding TrackProgressWidth,ElementName=audio}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" Margin="0,0,0,28" />
```

....
[image]

I need to change width of "HorizontalFillLoaded", like

```
var t=new AudioSlider();
t.SetDownloadedProgress(50);//50%
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the XAML is part of the template in the the default style:

Use `TemplateBinding` instead of `Binding`

Comment: If you change the width at runtime you will need to add a converter  to the binding that calculates the correct width to keep it in proportion.

Comment: can you help me find right direction how to do it? I don't understand what converter I need, how it will work.

Comment: I can not create anything without having better specs. Be more clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Rectangle TrackLoaded;
    public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
      base.OnApplyTemplate();
      Rectangle txtBoxValue = base.GetTemplateChild("HorizontalFillLoaded") as Rectangle;

      Binding valueBinding = new Binding("TrackProgressWidth");
      valueBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
      valueBinding.Source = this; txtBoxValue.SetBinding(Rectangle.WidthProperty,
       valueBinding);
    }
```